# Trigger pipeline on finished run of master branch of another pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline B that I want to run upon completion of pipeline A, but only on the master branch. I have followed the documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-filters) and the start of my pipeline B script now looks like this:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline A
      source:  pipeline B
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
```

However this causes pipeline B to also trigger on pushes to all branches. How can I make pipeline B only trigger on completion of master branch builds in pipeline A?

Comment: Are you specifying a `trigger` for pipeline B? The default behavior if you don't have a `trigger` section specified for a pipeline is to trigger on all pushes to all branches. You probably need a `- trigger: none`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a minor syntax error, as per the documentation you should have the word 'include' under the trigger before the branches

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline A
      source:  pipeline A
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
          - master
```

Comment: So I included the `include` keyword, but it still does not trigger when pipeline A completes.

Comment: @PalBo I've just realised your using source as pipeline B. This should be pipeline A since this is what you want to use to trigger pipeline B